# SoftLayer_Network_Storage.volumeStatus is not a string type

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have SoftLayer endurance block storage. Although SoftLayer API reference describes that the type of `volumeStatus` property is `string`, SoftLayer API returns a different result as follows:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/12345678.json?objectMask=mask[volumeStatus]

{
...
  "volumeStatus": {
    "createDate": "2017-01-26T02:22:39-05:00",
    "message": "Volume Provisioning has completed.",
    "scheduleId": null,
    "typeId": 314,
    "volumeId": 12345678
  }
```

What is a type of `volumeStatus`?

Answer (score 0):

try with this request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/5805095/getObject?objectMask=volumeStatus
```

Regards